# Django admin: Can I add a filter for a model method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've got a model method status(), which returns either - "OK", "WARNING", or "ERROR". The status can be displayed in Django admin by adding status to the list_display ModelAdmin option. What I would also like to do is activate a filter for status in Django admin. However, if I add status to the list_filter ModelAdmin option I get an error. Is there anyway to add a filter for a model method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only filter on database columns, so you're stuck.. As a workaround you could add filtering on source column from which you recognize the status, or add a new db column for status.

Comment: This answer is from 2010. Is it still correct? Isn't there a way to filter based not on a model's field but on a model's method?

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass admin.SimpleListFilter as described here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter